# Cross-Platform/Xamarin/VS: class exists in .IOS but not .Android and .UWP

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, cross-platform

In a Visual Studio 2017 cross-platform project, which I mostly based on the integrated Visual Studio example, I added a page .xaml + .cs files.

This page's class exists in the projects

"MyProject" and "MyProject".iOS

but is not known by

"MyProject".Android and "MyProject".UWP

What am I missing ?

Edit: I forgot this precision: I'm trying to build the project from 'Projec'>Store>Create App Packages ... if instead I Re-build, Re-deploy, Run, the project runs.

Comment: Typically pages will be created in the shared/PCL project, and then each platform project will have a reference to the shared project.  Do you mean you have copies of the class in two projects, or just that it is visible from the iOS project?

Comment: I only have copied of the class in the shared project.  Some xaml/cs page that I copied from VS example project and one that created and "harmonised" with the others. The one that I created and "harmonised" is only known by the .iOS project. But wait, I forgot this precision: I'm trying to build the project from 'Projec'>Store>Create App Packages ... if instead I Re-build, Re-deploy, Run, the project runs.